# Retrieve value from row in Swift List

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I get the value of the selected row in a list?

For example:

```
var data: [String] = []    

List {
   ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { item in
     HStack {
        Text(data[item])
     }
   }
} //: End of the List

.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
   // get the value of the row
   // get the corresponding key for the value
   // delete the value by the key from the dictionary
}) //: End of the onDelete

.onAppear {
   let dictionary = //retrieve the data from the database and get a dictionary
   for entry in dictionary {
      data.append(entry.value)
   }
} //: End of the onAppear
```

How I can get the value of a selected row of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If getting value of the deleted element is a must, then you can try it this way. Code is below the image.

If you only need the value of selected element, then just use `$selection`.

[image]

```
struct DemoView: View {
@State var list = ["dog", "cat", "turtle"]
@State var atIndex = 0
@State var temp = ""
var body: some View {
    List(selection: $temp) {
        ForEach(list, id: \.self) { sub in
            HStack {
                Text(sub)
            }
        }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
            indexSet.forEach { i in
                atIndex += i
            }
            temp = list[atIndex]
            print("I am going to delete \(temp)")
            list.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            atIndex = 0
        }
        Text("Recent deleted value: \(temp)")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `List` with selection constructor, like

```
var data: [String] = []    

@State private var selection: String?

List(selection: $selection) {     // << here !!
   ForEach(0..<data.count, id: \.self) { item in
// ...
```